# Error with list_route: POST methods in Viewset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am making a function Add Friend which user can Create one Friendship Request object to another user user URL:`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/{username}/add_friend/` but I get error when making.

**Code in Urls.py**

```
from .views import (AddFriendUserAPIView)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w-]+)/add_friend/$', AddFriendUserAPIView.as_view({'post': 'add_friend'}), name='add_friend'),
]
```

**Code in Views.py**

```
class AddFriendUserAPIView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FriendRequestSerializer
    queryset = FriendshipRequest.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'username'

    @detail_route(methods=['POST'])
    def add_friend(self, request, username):
        to_user = User.objects.get(username=request.data['to_user_username'])
        add_qs = FriendshipRequest.objects.get_or_create(from_user=request.user, to_user=to_user , message='')
        serializer = FriendRequestSerializer(add_qs)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Code in serializers.py**

```
class FriendRequestSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FriendshipRequest
        fields = (
            'id',
            'from_user',
            'to_user',
            'message', 
        )
```

Code in **Models** of Friend Requests:

```
class FriendshipRequest(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friendship_requests_sent')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friendship_requests_received')
    message = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

**Error log by Trackback**

```
    Traceback:

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py" in view
  90.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  489.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in handle_exception
  449.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  486.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\FeedGit\backend\api\authentication\add_friend.py" in add_friend
  16.         to_user = User.objects.get(username=request.data['to_user_username'])

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  85.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /api/v1/users/duongnuhabang/add_friend/
Exception Value: "'to_user_username'"
```

Comment: can you post your request

Comment: Updated Shiva! Please take a look

Comment: Once your problem is solved, please do not overwrite the question with the working code, and please refrain from adding [solved] hacks to the title. The acceptance system is more than enough. Remember that questions should be left in a condition that means they make sense in light of the answers received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's you again.You must has some misunderstanding about DRF.
First,you better use router to host your urls with `ModelViewSet`.like:

project/urls.py

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'user', UserViewSet, base_name='user')
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Second is what you need is `detail_router` not `list_router`:

views.py

```
class UserViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    lookup_field = username

    @detail_route(methods=['POST'])
    def add_friend(self, request, username):
        to_user = self.get_object()
        add_qs = FriendshipRequest.objects.get_or_create(from_user=request.user, to_user=to_user , message='')
        serializer = FriendRequestSerializer(add_qs)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Post data {} to `www.example.com/user/【to_user_username】/add_friend/`

---

If you really want to do this in FriendShipViewSet(you might more used to this style),here is demo:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'friendship', FriendShipViewSet, base_name='friendship')
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]


class FriendShipViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FriendShipRequestSerializer
    queryset = FriendShip.objects.all()

    @list_route(methods=['POST'])
    def add_friend(self, request):
        to_user = User.objects.get(username=request.data['to_user_username'])
        add_qs = FriendshipRequest.objects.get_or_create(from_user=request.user, to_user=to_user , message='')
        serializer = self.get_serializer(add_qs)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Post data `{'to_user_username': 'your_custom_to_user_username'}` to `www.example.com/friendship/add_friend/`

Comment: Why using FriendShipViewSet is not the best way. Can you give explain me more. I really dont understand!! I learn Django Rest Framework from this example: `https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Blog-API-with-Django-Rest-Framework/tree/master/src/posts/api`

Comment: Just personal style,nothing else.Use FriendShipViewSet still is a good way.

Comment: Use `FriendShipViewSet` you must handle `to_user = User.objects.get(username=request.data['to_user_username']) ` raise `ObjectDoesNotexist` except by yourself.Use `UserViewSet` DRF will handle this by `self.get_object()`

Comment: Thank you very much again. You continue to save my time, @Ykh! Vote the best for ya!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your `add_friend` accepts two parameters, being `self` and `request`. However, from your URL you are also passing the keyword argument `username`. The `username` argument is not in the parameters of your method and therefor cannot be passed as a parameter. Adding username as a parameter to your `add_friend` should fix the issue.

```
def add_friend(self, request, username):
     ...
```

Besides that, the username passed in your URL is never used in your `add_friend` method.

Comment: Please take a look my code I fixed above. Error because username field